# Find Second maximum date from two consecutive months - PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

I have a data table containing dates in two consecutive months and I need to find 2nd Maximum date from that using PL/SQL

| Date |
| --- |
| 02-OCT-2021 |
| 30-SEP-2021 |
| 29-SEP-2021 |
| 28-SEP-2021 |

My Query is,

```
select MAX(status_date) from A where status_date not in (select MAX(status_date) from A)
```

`29-SEP-2021` is query results but it should `30-SEP-2021`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help of analytic function (sample data in lines #1 - 6; `temp` CTE "calculates" rank of each `status_date`; final query (line #12 onward) returns the result):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> with a (status_date) as
  2    (select date '2021-10-02' from dual union all
  3     select date '2021-09-30' from dual union all
  4     select date '2021-09-29' from dual union all
  5     select date '2021-09-28' from dual
  6    ),
  7  temp as
  8    (select status_date,
  9            rank() over (order by status_date desc) rnk
 10     from a
 11    )
 12  select status_date
 13  from temp
 14  where rnk = 2;

STATUS_DAT
----------
30.09.2021

SQL>
```

Comment: `RANK` is the wrong function for this. If there are identical values with the latest date then there will be no row with a rank of 2. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ac5511da96ad07b85fabff2001932150)

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY date_column DESC
OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Before that, you can use:

```sql
SELECT date_column
FROM   (
  SELECT date_column,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_column DESC) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
  ORDER BY date_column DESC
)
WHERE rn = 2;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT date_column
FROM   (
  SELECT date_column,
         ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT date_column
    FROM   table_name
    ORDER BY date_column DESC
  )
)
WHERE rn = 2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0d7a4c2b351c92ffb44d6771f2c398a2)*